# Custom setText method only works once on UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I'm working on a project that includes making changes to `UILabel`.

This is the idea:

The `UILabel` has it's standard text entered by user + a `UITextField` under the text.

When long pressing the `UILabel`, it will show the description of that particular `UILabel` & hides the `UITextField`. When long pressing again, it should show the standard text again & show the `UITextField`.

The first part works: When long pressing, the description will be shown instead of the standard text & the `UITextField` is hidden. The `NSLog` also are correct.

However, when I long press again: The description text stays but the `UITextField` will show up again (because I said so in my code).

The `NSLog` however are telling me it DID change (I'm logging the UILabel.text).

This is the code:

```c
-(void)textfieldLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture {

    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        // getting the correct switch (UILabel)
        TextFieldSwitch *correctSwitch = (TextFieldSwitch *)[gesture view];

        // getting the switch text using a own generated method that returns the correct UILabel.text
        NSString *switchText = [correctSwitch getTextfieldSwitchText];

        // if the switch text is equal to the description, it should show the standard text again & show the UITextField
        if([switchText  isEqual: [correctSwitch getDescription]]) {
            [correctSwitch setTextfieldSwitchText:[correctSwitch getName]];
            [correctSwitch showTextField];
        } else {
            [correctSwitch setTextfieldSwitchText:[correctSwitch getDescription]];
            [correctSwitch hideTextField];
        }

        // log the standard name of the switch.
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", [correctSwitch getName]);

        //log the UILabel.text
        NSLog(@"TxtfieldLabel text: %@", [correctSwitch getTextfieldSwitchText]);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out, I would be gratefull!

Thankyou in advance.

Edit:

Code from TextFieldSwitch class:

```c
-(void)setTextfieldSwitchText:(NSString *)newText {
    textfieldSwitch.text = newText;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code of `TextFieldSwitch` class?

Comment: What part of it? It's lots of code..

Comment: mainly `setTextfieldSwitchText` method

Comment: Okay. I've added it on the bottom of the post.

Comment: its hard to detect, did you do debug to make sure that the if/else statement is correct , but generally try to use `isEqualToString:` instead of `isEqual:` when dealing with strings